# Elasticsearch Java API Unsupported Aggregation (Filter, range, ...)

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, aggregation

I keep getting an `Unsupported Aggregation` error for anything but "terms".

I'm building aggregations like:

`AggregationBuilders.filter(name).filter(FilterBuilders.wrapperFilter("[WRAPPED FILTER SOURCE]"));`

And adding it to the search with SearchRequestBuilder's `addAggregation`

When I use a terms aggregation, it works fine and returns buckets as expected. But a filter or range gives `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.InternalFilter` as an unsupported.

The strange thing is running the query (the one that the Java API gives on a to string) through the REST endpoint works fine.

Comment: Is your client Java application using the correct version of Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I'ts probably because you are not setting the field via the `.field("fieldName")` method as in `AggregationBuilders.sum("my_sum").field("fieldToSum")`. I believe you won't even need the `wrapperFilter` doing it this way.